# Forming a Dictionary from results

Tags: python-3.x

what is a more optimal and efficient way to add these result to a dictionary ?

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        if type (name) == str and type(age)  == int or type(age)  == float:

            self.name = name
            self.age = age
        else :
            raise ValueError ("data type error")

 s1 = Student ('Chris Sanford',22)
 s2 = Student (' Tate', 24)
 s3 = Student ('Adèle Bernard', 17)
 s4 = Student ('Gabrielle Francis.', 83)

 result = {s1.name: s1.age, s2.name: s2.age, s3.name: s3.age,  s4.name:s4.age}
 print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student:
def __init__(self, name, age):
    if type (name) == str and type(age)  == int or type(age)  == float:

        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    else :
        raise ValueError ("data type error")

 students = [Student('Chris Sanford',22), 
             Student(' Tate', 24),
             Student('Adèle Bernard', 17),
             Student ('Gabrielle Francis.', 83)]

 result = {student.name: student.age for student in students}
 print (result)
```

The expression `{student.name: student.age for student in students}` is called a dictionary comprehension and can be used to create a dictionary using items from a list to provide data for each key: pair value. In this case `student in students` means "For each element in the iterable named `students` give me it in a variable named `student` which you can then use in the left side of the expression before the word `for`

Comment: Personally, I would use ``isinstance()`` instead of ``type()`` as it supports inheritance and is generally better than the latter.

Comment: I didn't bother with the whole validation part. that isn't how I'd go about it at all, but it wasn't really part of their question so I decided not to touch it

Comment: please if you have any improvement comment just add it am pretty new to programming, and always seeking to make it perfect.

Comment: Well as stated above, `isinstance()` is generally better to use because it takes into account inheritance from classes, normally I'd go about verifying the types of a var in a different way or using an EAFP style. in this case, I think it would be clearer and simpler to use `if type(name) in (str, int) or type(age) in (float,):`